# initState() taking too long to load

Tags: flutter, dart

I have home screen which two tabs. now when I get to home tab and got to search instantly. I get red screen for slight second and then all widgets get loaded.

Now where problem is,

in `initState()` I'm assigning `store.filteredPOI` to `widget.floorPlan.pois`.

I'm getting `store.filteredPOI` from a network call which will take some time. so in that fraction of time `widget.floorPlan` is null so how can I show a loader to prevent the red error screen,

code

```
class SearchTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final FloorPlan floorPlan;
  final bool isIndoorMapVisible;
  final NetworkStatus networkStatus;
  SearchTab({this.floorPlan, this.isIndoorMapVisible,this.networkStatus});

  @override
  _SearchTabState createState() => _SearchTabState();
}

class _SearchTabState extends State<SearchTab> {
  final TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
  SearchStore store;

  @override
  void initState() {
    store = SearchStore();
    store.filteredPOI = widget.floorPlan.pois; //<<<<<<<<
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (...)
```

Comment: try to move super.initState();  at the first line and compile again.

Comment: return widget.floorPlan == null ? Text("Loading") : OtherWidget(...);

Comment: @AfridiKayal Kayal actually the error is coming from initState itself. so it is not even reaching to build method.

Comment: @khoi that doesn't work

Comment: then you need to make sure that the value is a pass-first at variable floorPlan then call SearchTab(). Need to create a flag to identify if the value already receives from the network or not. I don't know your full code, but something like this  --->    Scaffold(
body: isReceiveValueFromNetwork ? SearchTab(floorPlan:floorPlan,..) : Text("loading..");
);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: @Pokaboom What is the error message?

Comment: @AfridiKayal error was `widget.floorPlan` is called on null but what ended up doing was added the the assignment operation in the build method so now it working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I ended up doing was add the operation inside built method

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   store.filteredPOI = widget.floorPlan.pois;
    return (...)
```